# convert string with decimals to integer

Tags: c

In C what is the best way to convert a string in such a format as "293.0000" to the float result 2.93.

By the way is it also possible to remove the decimals with printf and get a result of 293

Comment: Can you clarify a bit. you say convert a string to integer 2.93? That isnt an integer, if you mean 293. You can use atoi to convert a string to an integer. You can then printf this using %d in the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *myNum = "293.0000";
double myDouble = atof(myNum);
int myInt = (int)myDouble;
myDouble /= 100;
printf("double: (%.2f) %f, int: %d\n", myDouble, myDouble, myInt);
```

output:

> double: (2.93) 2.930000, int: 293

Note that floating-point types are going to have precision beyond 2 decimal points. When you output them you need to limit that to what you want.

Comment: I am getting this output double: (.22.930000) 2.930000, int: 293

Comment: That is because there is a typo in the answer, it should be (%.2f) inside the printf statement.

Comment: I was about to say that `atof` converts to float, not double.  Fortunately, I looked it up first; `atof` returns a double, and there is no `atod`.  But all the `ato*()` function suffer from a lack of error checking.  The `strto*()` functions are trickier to use, but can handle things like `"1.0e99999999999999"` and `"hello"`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to convert the "293.00000" string to the integer value of 293.

It's not the fastest way and you need the C library (can't use it in kernel space), but it's a clean and straightforward approach:

```
float tmp;
long result;

sscanf("293.00000", "%f", &tmp);

result = lrintf(tmp);
```